# how to reduce native heap usage in google map for android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, out-of-memory

> 10-15 14:43:43.020: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(299): 32768-byte external allocation too large for this process. 10-15 14:43:43.020: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(299): VM won't let us allocate 32768 bytes 10-15 14:43:43.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-15 14:43:43.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget 10-15 14:43:43.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) 10-15 14:43:43.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)

This is the error I am getting when I use overlaying on google map ! I have checked native heap usage using [this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238388/android-out-of-memory-exception-in-gallery/3238945#3238945).

When I get the error I see a native heap usage of almost 50%

> 10-16 13:40:01.658: INFO/System.out(1661): alloc: 7.0171661376953125 : available: 7.10546875

Can anyone please help me out on this issue ? Thanks.

-
ahsan