# ListView slow performance

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I've created a list of recipes using Listview/customcursoradapter. A custom layout includes a photo for the recipe , Now I've some problems with the performance of viewing and scrolling the `ListView` although it has only 10 records (Target is 150). Sometimes I get this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`, I've tried to implement the `AsyncTask` but I failed to do it. Is there any way I can overcome this problem?

Your help is highly appreciated !!

Here is my `getView` method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Cursor cursbbn  = getCursor();
    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) localContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listtype, null);
    }

    String Title = cursbbn.getString(2);
    String SandID=cursbbn.getString(1);
    String Readyin = cursbbn.getString(4);
    String Faovoites=cursbbn.getString(8);

    TextView titler=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listmaintitle);
    TextView readyinr=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listreadyin);

    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    row.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    titler.setText(Title);
    readyinr.setText(Readyin);

    ImageView picture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bitmap bitImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0001);
    Bitmap bitImg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0002);
    Bitmap bitImg3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0003);
    Bitmap bitImg4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0004);
    Bitmap bitImg5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0005);
    Bitmap bitImg6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0006);
    Bitmap bitImg7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0007);
    Bitmap bitImg8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0008);
    Bitmap bitImg9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0009);
    Bitmap bitImg10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0010);

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0001"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg1));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0002"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg2));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0003"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg3));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0004"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg4));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0005"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg5));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0006"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg6));
    if(SandID.contentEquals("0007"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg7));
    if(SandID.contentEquals("0008"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg8));
    if(SandID.contentEquals("0009"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg9));

    if(SandID.contentEquals("0010"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg10));

    return row;
}
```

And This is the error :

```
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:359)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:385)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at master.chef.mediamaster.AlternateRowCursorAdapter.getView(AlternateRowCursorAdapter.java:83)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:700)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:646)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3399)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2233)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 03:11:55.898: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are not making use of convertView, you should start like,

```
View view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
  // inflate
}
```

here's a blog post that talks about using convertView,

> http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html

Second, you should only decode the bitmaps for which you know you will use. so change your method like,

```
if(SandID.contentEquals("0001"))
    Bitmap bitImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.rec0001);
    picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg1));
...
```

Third, can you decode them once, and have them available outside this method? for example, decode them once in the constructor and store them as instance members in your adapter class, then just use them in `getView()`.

Fourth, are you recycling your bitmaps? bitmaps are allocated differently than other objects and need to have their `recycle()` method called on them when you are finished using them. If you can implement the third item above, you can avoid this complexity for the most part, although you should still release them when your activity is stopped, re-allocate them when it's started.

There's lots of good information on SO about `Bitmap.recycle()` and i'd recommend you spend some time researching it. Explaining the intricacies is beyond what can be accomplished in a post here. Here's one good SO post covering the topic,

> [Bitmap, Bitmap.recycle(), WeakReferences, and Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959485/bitmap-bitmap-recycle-weakreference-and-garbage-collector)

Comment: I've tried to implement the convert view but i get the 10 records with the same name???

Comment: its not the case when i use the View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Comment: the convert view is a "recycled" view. you still need to set all of the values into the various text / image / etc views. the only different is you can avoid inflating a new view, which is quite costly.