# MonoDroid: About Bitmap.Recycle() and Bitmap.Dispose()

Tags: android, bitmap, mono, xamarin.android, dispose

Do I still need to call `Bitmap.Dispose()` after `Bitmap.Recycle()`? Or just `Bitmap.Dispose()` is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Android documentation [Bitmap.Recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) should be enough:

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data.

[Mono for Android documentation](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M:Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Recycle%28%29) says exactly the same.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959485/bitmap-bitmap-recycle-weakreference-and-garbage-collector) gets a little further on how Bitmap.Recycle works.

Comment: After replacing the old code `bitmap?.Dispose()` to `bitmap?.Recycle()` the app I'm fixing acts weirdly. Also, the bitmap gets distorted

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to wrap in a `using` statement:

```
using (var bm = new Bitmap(..))
{
    // Do stuff with the Bitmap here
}
```

Just remember that when you leave the scope of the using statement, the Bitmap will probably be garbage collected. So if you are just drawing it to a `Canvas` or something this is a nice way to do it.