# Custom List Adapter unbind views

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, listadapter, bitmapsource

I have developed a custom list adapter where i have attach views using holder. also i have checked if the views are already crated and reusing them again and again. The listview is inside the fragment and when I am navigating to another fragment I am using fragmenttransaction.replace . But issue is that when i monitor the dump file using MAT I found the imageview that were present inside adapter still hold the reference to bitmaps. Even different others views had the reference.

I want to know how to remove reference to that views?

Comment: You can clean the imageview by giving a null object. However, until garbage collection was not started it's absolutily ok still having those objects in memory.

Comment: `if (mBitmap != null) {
    mBitmap.recycle();
    mBitmap = null;
}`

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959485/bitmap-bitmap-recycle-weakreferences-and-garbage-collection) for more on memory mgt.

Comment: @mek the post you referred i have done that way, but issue is that the hard reference is still prevailing to the ImageView inside the adapter. And that resist the GC to recycle bitmaps. So I need way to remove reference to views inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

try to setAdapter(null); and you can try to use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Comment: Actually i did that where i used my adapter. But makes only adapter null not its views inside it, so the views that are inside adapter have reference.