# How can I solve this bitmap memory leak on Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bitmap

I am facing a big problem with Bitmap memory leak.

[image: this is the dump]

This memory dump shows the Bitmap never go way but stay in the heap and it causes ARN.

How can I solve this?

This is mostly used in Adapter.

Comment: If you could provide more detail on how you are creating the resource and then cleaning it up that would help in providing an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitmap, Bitmap.recycle(), WeakReferences, and Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959485/bitmap-bitmap-recycle-weakreferences-and-garbage-collection)