# Reference counting android Bitmaps with caches

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, out-of-memory

On Android pre-honeycomb, Bitmaps have freaky memory issues because their data isn't stored in the VM. As a result it isn't tracked or removed by the GC. Instead it is removed when `Bitmap.recycle()` is called (and that is also done automatically in the `Bitmap`'s finalizer).

This leads to some problems when doing image caching. When a bitmap is due to be evicted, I can't simply call `recycle()` on it, because I have no idea if anyone else is using it.

My first thought was to do `System.gc()` just before I load each bitmap. That way, hopefully orphaned `Bitmap`s will be finalized and the native memory freed. But [it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4348208/265521). *Edit: Actually it does sort of work. I had my `System.gc()` in the wrong place, after moving it, and halving my cache size (to what seems like a ridiculously small 2 MB of uncompressed bitmap data), my app no longer seems to crash (so far)!*

My next thought was to implement manual reference counting, by subclassing `Bitmap` and calling `ReferenceCountedBitmap.decrementCount()` in all my activities' `onDestroy()` methods. But I can't because `Bitmap` is final.

I am now planning a `BitmapManager` which keeps `WeakReference`'s to the bitmaps, and has methods like:

```
public void using(Bitmap bm);
public void free(Bitmap bm);
```

which count the references.

Does anyone have any experience or advice handling this? Before you suggest it, I can't ignore 80% of the market.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this with a bitmap manager, where I save the referencing views. In a map-like structure bitmap -> list of views.

Before I call `recycle()` on a bitmap, I first set all the references from the views to null (otherwise it will throw bitmap recycled exception).

Manual garbage collection, as you say, doesn't work for bitmaps pre-honeycomb, since they are allocated in the native heap and even with `System.gc()` you can't make assumptions when this memory will be released.