# Reading Big Assets File Throws OutofMemory Exception

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am trying to read an assets file using InputStream but it throws OutOfMemory Exception , the size of file is 22 mb ( about 22 Million Bytes ! )

This is the code I use

```
try{
    java.io.InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("file.json");
               int Si = is.available();
               byte[] Bu = new byte[Si];
               is.read(Bu);
               is.close();
               data = new String(Bu, "UTF-8");
}catch(Exception e){
     
}
```

Comment: But why would you place a big file completely in a byte buffer in memory? Makes ni sense to me. And not enough: After that you create a string fir that byte buffer. Hence it would be in memory twice. Wonder why you are doing this.

Comment: separate to several files

Comment: Well even then that is not needed. And converting a byte buffer to string neither. You mean 22 MB. Not 22 mb.

Comment: You may not be able to hold 22MB of parsed JSON in memory. But, you will have better luck if you pass the `InputStream` to your JSON parser (Moshi, Gson, Jackson, etc.), rather than trying to read it in yourself.

Comment: Could please refer to method name or something in the gson library that read directly from inputstream?

Comment: Like @CommonsWare correctly said lots of library do provide option to read large Json files using Streams, however that also depends on your Json Structure, assuming it would be a big array of lots of similar Json Structures(Objects) it would be possible to use these libraries.

Comment: Use `fromJson()` on a `Gson` instance, wrapping your `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`. See https://github.com/google/gson/issues/187#issuecomment-83702155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare said , just I have to use this

```
((java.io.Reader)(new java.io.InputStreamReader(ContextOfClass.getAssests().open("file name"))))
```

In my gson json to listmap/liststring/etc code

Answer (score -1):

add `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14764576/16177121)

> make sure you don't have two copies of the data in memory. You can null out the reference to the old ArrayList before starting to create the new one, though you have to do that carefully -- calling ArrayList.clear() first would be more thorough.

Comment: I would try this , thank you for answer

Comment: @ArabWare does it not worked for you?