# memory out of bound exception using high quality images in Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

Hi I am new in mobile app development. I am having problem using a gallery widget. I am using few images of high quality for the galley. But when I am scrolling the gallery sometime the app is getting crashed, and I am getting "memory out of bound exception". But It is working fine when I am using low quality images.

How to overcome this problem, so that I can use good quality images for my gallery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you to refer following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238945/1554935

Comment: you can also refer to following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?lq=1