# OutOfMemory error though free memory is available

Tags: android, bitmap, jvm, android-3.0-honeycomb, dalvik

I'm seeing a pretty odd problem. Essentially sometimes large bitmap memory allocations will fail even though there's apparently tons of memory. There are a number of posts that appear to ask a similar question but they are all related to pre-honeycomb android. My understanding is that images are allocated on heap now, instead of some outside memory. Anyway, please look at this log below:

```
    10-14 13:43:53.020: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(31533): Grow heap (frag case) to 40.637MB for 942134-byte allocation
    10-14 13:43:53.070: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 11% free 41399K/46343K, paused 31ms
    10-14 13:43:53.130: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 920K, 13% free 40478K/46343K, paused 30ms
    10-14 13:43:53.180: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1026K, 13% free 40479K/46343K, paused 30ms
    10-14 13:43:53.250: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 931K, 12% free 41193K/46343K, paused 31ms
    10-14 13:43:53.250: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(31533): Grow heap (frag case) to 41.313MB for 1048592-byte allocation
    10-14 13:43:53.280: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 42217K/47431K, paused 31ms
    10-14 13:44:01.520: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3493K, 15% free 40646K/47431K, paused 3ms+9ms
    10-14 13:44:08.130: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_EXPLICIT freed 16461K, 47% free 25527K/47431K, paused 3ms+6ms
    10-14 13:44:09.150: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1007K, 45% free 26191K/47431K, paused 35ms
    10-14 13:44:09.160: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(31533): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.334MB for 3850256-byte allocation
    10-14 13:44:09.200: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 37% free 29951K/47431K, paused 2ms+4ms
    10-14 13:44:11.970: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1878K, 38% free 29784K/47431K, paused 37ms
    10-14 13:44:12.410: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 36% free 30441K/47431K, paused 32ms
    10-14 13:44:12.440: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 32% free 32325K/47431K, paused 32ms
    10-14 13:44:12.440: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(31533): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3850256-byte allocation
    10-14 13:44:12.480: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31533): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 124K, 33% free 32200K/47431K, paused 37ms
    10-14 13:44:12.480: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(31533): Out of memory on a 3850256-byte allocation.
```

I apologise for including so much logging, I hope it's relevant. The way I read it is that the  system continuously readjusts heap size until it eventually reaches heap max. Then, we request an especially large allocation that fails. Clearly there is more than enough memory available (about 15 megs). Does this mean that heap is internally fragmented and there are no contiguous memory segments large enough to handle our allocation? If that's the case what should I do? If that's not it, then what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using softreferences?

Comment: Not directly, although 3rd last line says something about SoftReferences. I'm using a google-collections based cache which uses WeakReferences as far as I know.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on an S3 on OS 4.1.2, with apparently even more free memory available:
10-02 14:28:22.458  5333  9044 D dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 54% free 30274K/65543K, paused 120ms, total 120ms

Answer (score 16):

The weird behavior is because bitmaps are allocated on the native heap and not on the garbage collected, but android can only track objects on the garbage collected heap. From Android 2.2 (or 2.3 maybe) this has changed and allocated bitmaps are visible too if you make a heap dump.

Back to the question, your problem is most probably that the bitmaps you loaded manually are not freed appropriately. One typical problem is that some callback remains set or the view is still referring the bitmap.
The other common problem is that if you load big bitmaps manually (not as a resource), you will need to call recycle() on them when you don't need it anymore, which will free the bitmap from the native memory so the garbage collector will be able to its work as it should. (The GC only sees objects on the GC heap, and doesn't no which object to free to free memory from the native heap, and actually doesn't even care about it.)

I have this little baby at hand all the time:

```
public static void stripImageView(ImageView view) {
    if ( view.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable ) {
        ((BitmapDrawable)view.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
    }
    view.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
    view.setImageDrawable(null);
    view.getResources().flushLayoutCache();
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct for honeycomb hege. Images are allocated on the app heap I believe -- based on this Google IO 2011 talk (slide 18 http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/memory_management_for_android_apps.pdf). Anecdotally, I see my app heap grow when I allocate a large bitmap, and shrink when I release it (with the code similar to what you posted)>

Comment: Yap, I've told you :) "From Android 2.2 (or 2.3 maybe) this has changed..."

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be sufficient, not sure why. The recycle/etc does not seem to have an effect on the heap size (at least on this 4.0 device).

Answer (score 2):

> The images are fetched from the Web, each ranging from 300K to 500K in
>   size, and stored in an arrayList of Drawables.

The kb file size of the image you're loading from the web isn't directly relevant. Since they're converted into bitmaps you need to calculate width * height * 4 bytes per image for regular ARGB images. (width and height in px).

The bitmaps consume native heap, which usually doesn't show in a hprof. The hprof should only show you the number of objects, i.e. BitmapDrawables or Bitmaps that are left.

I use this code in my app to output the current used memory used by the app and native heap:

```
public static void logHeap(Class clazz) {
    Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())/new Double((1048576));
    Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize())/1048576.0);
    Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize())/1048576.0);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    Log.d(APP, "debug. =================================");
    Log.d(APP, "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated) + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free) + "MB free) in [" + clazz.getName().replaceAll("com.myapp.android.","") + "]");
    Log.d(APP, "debug.memory: allocated: " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1048576)) + "MB of " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1048576))+ "MB (" + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1048576)) +"MB free)");
    System.gc();
    System.gc();

    // don't need to add the following lines, it's just an app specific handling in my app        
    if (allocated>=(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())/new Double((1048576))-MEMORY_BUFFER_LIMIT_FOR_RESTART)) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

which I call when starting or finishing an activity during development.

```
logHeap(this.getClass());
```

Here are some informative links - generally there are lots of threads about this topic on here.

- [Bitmaps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945142/bitmaps-in-android)
- [Android: Eclipse MAT does not appear to show all my app's objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203806/android-eclipse-mat-does-not-appear-to-show-all-my-apps-objects)

Here's also a useful slide by Romain Guy (Android Framework engineer) about soft references, weak references, simple caches, image handling: http://docs.huihoo.com/google/io/2009/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mehul. Unfortunately all of your resources predate Honeycomb. I will examine your source cod.e

Answer (score 0):

yes the error "out of Memory" occur when we are working with big size Bitmap. for that i have an solution, with Decoding of the image we can easily avoid this error.

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files.getAbsolutePath());
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
fis.close();
final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
int scale=1;
while(true){
if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
break;
width_tmp/=2;
height_tmp/=2;
scale*=2;
}
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inSampleSize = scale;
fis = new FileInputStream(files.getAbsolutePath());
bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, op);
fis.close();
```

Comment: So you're rescaling the image when you get an OOM? I guess that's a potential solution, but it doesn't answer my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The system doesn't readjust heap sizes.  Your app has a (semi-) predefined heap space.  Heap sizes can be adjusted in some custom ROMs.  This isn't really germane to your problem though.

The order of the garbage collection you're seeing seems to suggest that at the time of the GC_BEFORE_OOM happens your app's running out of its heap space.  The stats reported by the Dalvik logger could be system-wide.

Comment: The number in the brackets is the process ID, so the stats reported are per process, not system wide.. I'm trying to resolve this incongruity. Dalvik's reporting 30% of memory available and the very next line indicates that memory has been exhausted. Bizarre.